# How to split string by multiple strings if followed by specific character

Tags: c#, .net

I receive bytecode and try to interpret it.
Since this is a communication between two devices using the HART protocol (primary/secondary), I wanted to sort the bytes first.

A request which starts with 82 and the answer which starts with 86.
Between them can be any number of FFs (Depending on how many come through), which serve as preambles.

Here is an example output:

```
82 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 00 59  FF FF FF FF FF 86 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 1A 00 00 41 4C BE B2 3B 40 F6 4D B7 24 C2 23 B2 40 20 41 B5 BA 3D AA 7F A0 00 00 20 FF FF FF FF 
82 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 00 59     FF FF FF FF 86 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 1A 00 00 41 4C BE D5 3B 40 F6 4D F5 24 C2 23 B2 40 20 41 B5 63 04 AA 7F A0 00 00 E5 FF FF FF FF 
82 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 00 59  FF FF FF FF FF 86 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 1A 00 00 41 4C BE F6 3B 40 F6 4E 2E 24 C2 23 B2 40 20 41 B5 76 E7 AA 7F A0 00 00 E8 FF FF FF FF 
82 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 00 59  FF FF FF FF FF 86 05 C6 00 46 5D 03 1A 00 00 41 4C BF 01 3B 40 F6 4E 41 24 C2 23 B2 40 20 41 B5 67 34 AA 7F A0 00 00 B3 FF FF FF FF
```

Here is my attempt to separate the requests and responses:

```
string[] delimiterChars = {
    "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF FF ",
    "FF FF ",
    "FF "
};

string[] words = OnlyHex.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This works fine, but unfortunately there can be FFs in the messages, which my code does not catch.

I could add these to each string array entry of delimiterChars but I don't think that would be the prettiest solution and would make it impossible to separate the request from the response as the numbers would then be missing.

How could I make it so that the string is only spearated, if the following part starts with an 82 or 86?
The 82 and 86 should be still in the split string. The FFs do not have to.

Probably the solution is Regex, but unfortunately I'm not a pro at it.

Comment: What do you mean by "there can be FFs in the messages, which my code does not catch"?

Comment: I would work with byte, but in any case I suggest you do some functional work in paper and the translate to code, test it and come with a question more clean

Comment: @Gec It can happen that FFs apear inside of the request or response and not only as the preambel. With my attempt, it would split the string at a wrong position.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli yes that would be ideal. This is my first time working with bytes in this kind of sense. I thought using regex and splitting the string would work out

Comment: So, 0x82 and 0x86 cannot be part of the message? Then I would: 1. Split by those, 2. If the "preambles" do not serve any deeper purpose: remove FFs from the end of the message until there is something different than FF (or no more message). If they _do_ have a purpose: count how many FFs I removed and somehow convey that information ...

Comment: ^^ Not going into that you should be using bytes to avoid performance and memory impact of using strings.

Comment: Not every sequence of bytes is “bytecode”. Besides that, processing a sequence of bytes by performing string manipulations on a hexdump is neither straight-forward nor efficient. I think, that’s what Leandro Bardelli meant. Instead of using strings, interpret the bytes according to the protocol, you apparently already know.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use regex for that. It will look something like this:

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(input[0], "(?<request>82.*)(?<answer>86.*)");
var request = match.Groups["request"].Value; // empty string for invalid input
var answer = match.Groups["answer"].Value;   // empty string for invalid input
```

It seems however strange that you are using strings to store this type of data. A byte array seems better feet, but then you cannot any longer use regex.

I suppose you will be using the answer and response later on, so your problem seems like a good candidate for parser generators. I suggest you look at [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache) or [Superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower).